# excluding URL query parameters and setting the site search query param in Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, search, site-search

I have a Google Analytics free account and would like to know if I strip "searchparam" out of your URLs as the `site search query parameter`, do I then need to specify "searchparam" in the `Exclude URL Query Parameters` field under Profiles > Profile Settings?

Or is this unnecessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is redundant for excluded internal site search query parameters to also be listed in the Exclude URL Query Parameters field for the profile.

Answer (score 1):

If you do mention "searchparam" in the Exclude URL Query Parameters, then GA will treat requests to the following two URL's

- yoursite.com/some/page/?searchparam=this
- yoursite.com/some/page/?searchparam=that

as the same requested page (infact it won't even show you the different search parameters being searched, instead it will club up the visits on both the URLs and show you an aggregate metric.

If that's what you want then go ahead and exclude searchparam in your Profile Settings.

Comment: So are you saying that I *have* to do that, or I don't have to exclude "searchparam" in Profile Settings?

Comment: Yes, you have to exclude searchparam in Profile Settings.